# AWS SES Email Sending error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, email, smtp, amazon-ses

Since my account on AWS is at sandbox so I created two email addresses in aws and verified them. Then I created SMTP credentials. I have used the credentials in my PHP mailer function but it keeps on saying Couldn't connect to the SMTP host. No idea what I am doing wrong here. One thing more here is that If I use Cpanel or any other SMTP settings instead of aws then this script works which means there is nothing wrong with the script.

Phpmailer function

```
function sendMail($data){


        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        try {
            //Server settings
            // $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
            $mail->Host       = MAIL_HOST;                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = MAIL_USERNAME;                     // SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = MAIL_PASSWORD;                               // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;    
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                   

            
            $mail->setFrom(MAIL_FROM, MAIL_NAME);
           
            $mail->addAddress($data['to'],$data['name']);               
            $mail->addReplyTo(MAIL_REPLYTO);
            // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
            //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

          
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
            $mail->Subject = $data['subject'];
            $mail->Body    = $data['message'];
            //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            $mail->send();
            $array['code'] = 200;
            $array['msg'] = "success";

            return $array;
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $array['code'] = 201;
            $array['msg'] =  $mail->ErrorInfo;

            return $array;
        }

    }
```

Error:

```
We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
<br>
2021-02-19 08:55:59 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO domain.com
    <br>
2021-02-19 08:55:59 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-ip-172.xx.xx.xxx.sysadmin.info Hello domain.com [172.xx.xx.xxx]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
        <br>
2021-02-19 08:55:59 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS
            <br>
2021-02-19 08:55:59 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
                <br>
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
                    <br>
2021-02-19 08:55:59 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT
                        <br>
2021-02-19 08:55:59 
                            <br>
2021-02-19 08:55:59 
                                <br>
```

On the terminal, I did this as well to check if the port is open

```
       Nmap -p587 IP
```

Result:

```
Host is up (0.00036s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
587/tcp open  submission
```

If I put this command

```
 telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 587
    telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 25
```

It says

```
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

No idea why I am not able to send an email from the script to my verified email address. Please help

Comment: The reason is clear: _"We do not authorize the use of this system..."_. There's something wrong with the way your Amazon SES account is set up.

Comment: SES doesn't present a smtp banner like this, it appears MAIL_HOST is set to something else, I would like to define email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com directly in the code instead of variable and test.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my settings that work for me:

```
.......
.......
$port = 587;
.......
.......

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    // Specify the SMTP settings.
    $mail->isSMTP(true);
    $mail->setFrom($sender, $senderName);
    $mail->Username   = $usernameSmtp;
    $mail->Password   = $passwordSmtp;
    $mail->Host       = $host;
    $mail->Port       = $port;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    //$mail->addCustomHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', $configurationSet);

.......
.......
```

PS: make sure you have the following things in order:

- If you're using port 465, change the value of SMTPSecure to ssl.
- Check if your instance is able to send outbound requests through these ports.
- The user needs an IAM role to be able to send emails through.